# What's at physical memory address zero?

Tags: linux, memory, x86

What's at Linux physical memory address zero?

Using QEMU monitor, I can see something like this...
What are these?

```
0000000000000000: 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53 0xf000e2c3 0xf000ff53
0000000000000010: 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53
0000000000000020: 0xf000fea5 0xf000e987 0xf000c96e 0xf000c96e
0000000000000030: 0xf000c96e 0xf000c96e 0xf000ef57 0xf000c96e
0000000000000040: 0xc00083f9 0xf000f84d 0xf000f841 0xf000e3fe
0000000000000050: 0xf000e739 0xf000f859 0xf000e82e 0xf000efd2
0000000000000060: 0xf000c98a 0xf000e6f2 0xf000fe6e 0xf000ff53
0000000000000070: 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53 0xf000d2b8 0xc000133e
0000000000000080: 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53
0000000000000090: 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53
00000000000000a0: 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53
00000000000000b0: 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53
00000000000000c0: 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53
00000000000000d0: 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53
00000000000000e0: 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53
00000000000000f0: 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53
0000000000000100: 0xf000ec59 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53 0xc000253e
0000000000000110: 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53
0000000000000120: 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53
0000000000000130: 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53
0000000000000140: 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53
0000000000000150: 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53
0000000000000160: 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53
0000000000000170: 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53
0000000000000180: 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000
0000000000000190: 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0xf000ff53
00000000000001a0: 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53
00000000000001b0: 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53
00000000000001c0: 0xf000c953 0xf000e2ba 0xf000e2ba 0xf000e2ba
00000000000001d0: 0xf000c95c 0xf000c965 0xf000c94a 0xf000e2ba
00000000000001e0: 0xf000ff53 0x00000000 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53
00000000000001f0: 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53
0000000000000200: 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53
0000000000000210: 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53 0xf000ff53
```

it is the result of

```
(QEMU) xp/500x 0x0
```

can someone explain?

Comment: on traditional x86 real-mode systems, the lowest few kbytes of ram contained the system interrupt tables. no idea if that's still true with modern virtualized memory

Comment: The question is not about [qemu] so I removed that tag.  If [x86] is wrong, please [edit] and use the specific architecture.

Comment: @MarcB: yeah it's still the same for modern cpus ;)